# how to get numbers of android downloaded app via API

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to display in a custom dashboard for a particular Android app the total number of download . Are there APIs that give me that value?

Comment: Downloaded from where?

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only api that is available is [this](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started) one, and it's only for editing/publishing your own apps' details.

If you want to get information on other apps I suggest you look into scraping the play store. The play store has some pretty standard (read: straightforward) url patterns to help you find the apps you want. If you have the apps package you can find the app straight away: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smithyproductions.infinitracks. There're similar patterns for search terms and finding apps by a particular developer too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Play Store API that would allow you access to this information.  There are a few 3rd party APIs, but these are somewhat unreliable, and un-official (so could go away at any time).

Bottom line, it is NOT possible to get download information from an official API at this time.